# JMS Serializer - Deserialize a json array into ArrayCollection

Tags: php, json, deserialization, jms-serializer

I'm using jms-serializer library to convert json data from an API in entities of my model.

In some cases I receive a list of items, but these are not encapsulated in the property of an object, just a plain json array.

```
[
    { "id": 1, "data": "foo" },
    { "id": 2, "data": "bar" },
    { "id": 3, "data": "baz" }
]
```

Wich is the best approach to convert these unwrapped arrays in entities inherited from ArrayCollection using JMS Serializer?